# Any open source or licenseable spend analysis front end toolkits?

Tags: dataset, visualization, dashboard

I'm looking for any libraries or code tool-kits to create a front end of sorts where a user can drill down through data, apply filters, perform a spend analysis of recent purchases. Is there anything like this out there? I'm thinking similar to how there are admin themes for rails apps that give you some basic data viewing capabilities except I want something that can be used to filter and drill down into a data-set and would show graphs and charts summarizing categorical data.

An image search for "spend analysis dashboard" gives some good examples of the style of GUI toolkit I'm thinking about.

Comment: Hi, do you mean something like charts? http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Charts or do you mean something like ActiveAdmin? (it's great for admin and generating dashboards... well, mostly for admin, but you can make your pivots).

Comment: I guess I'm thinking of a combination of both. I've seen the railscasts and Active Admin. But I'm looking for a framework that will handle adding and removing of "widgets", drill down from summary aggregate data into specific transactions. The framework would also handle saving the state of the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

[Spotfire](http://spotfire.tibco.com/) and [Tableau](http://www.tableausoftware.com/) are amazing commercial tools for analyzing multivariate datasets, and Spotfire especially is incredibly easy to use to explore lots of visualizations side-by-side. Both have a desktop version and an online web player ([Spotfire demo gallery](http://spotfire.tibco.com/demo/default.aspx), [Tableau demo gallery](http://www.tableausoftware.com/learn/gallery)). They are both highly scalable, into the millions of rows. Both are expensive but have free trials.

If you want ideas about how to do interactive filtering of datasets, creating many different charts along the way, you should check out this paper from CHI '12 and it's [demo video](http://youtu.be/Wic49KHXf88?hd=1).

- Dunne C, Riche NH, Lee B, Metoyer RA and Robertson GG (2012), "GraphTrail: Analyzing large multivariate, heterogeneous networks while supporting exploration history", In CHI '12: Proc. 2012 international conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems. pp. 1663-1672. [DOI:10.1145/2207676.2208293](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2207676.2208293) [Link to PDF](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~cdunne/hcil/pubs/Dunne12GraphTrail_analyzinglarge.pdf).
  *Disclaimer: I am one of the authors.*

[image: GraphTrail interface]